# Node.js: multi-part file upload via REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, multer

I would like to upload invoking a REST endpoint in multi-part.

In particular, I am looking at this API: [Google Cloud Storage: Objects: insert](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert)

I did read about using **multer**, however I did not find any complete example showing me how to perform this operation.

Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage#uploading_to_cloud_storage

^^ this is a a good example of how to use multer to upload a single image to Google Cloud Storage. Use multer to create filestream for each file ( storage: multer.memoryStorage() ), and handle the file stream by sending it to your GCS bucket in your callback.

However link only shows an example for one image. If you want to do an array of images, create a for-loop, where you create a stream for each file in your request, but only put the *next()* function after the for loop ends. If you keep the *next();* in each loop cycle you will get the error: *Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.*

Answer (score 0):

There is [an example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage) for uploading files with the [nodejs client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) and [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). You can modify this example and set the multipart option:

1. Download the sample code and cd into the folder:

   `git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/`

   `cd nodejs-docs-samples/appengine/storage`
2. Edit the `app.yaml` file and include your bucket name:

   `GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: YOUR_BUCKET_NAME`
3. Then in the source code, you can modify the `publicUrl` variable according to [Objects: insert](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#request)  example:

   ```
   const publicUrl = format(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/${bucket.name}/o?uploadType=multipart`);
   ```
4. Download a key file for your service account and set the environment variable:

   - Go to the Create service account key page in the GCP Console.
   - From the Service account drop-down list, select New service account.
   - Input a name into the Service account name field.
   - From the Role drop-down list, select Project > Owner.
   - Click Create. A JSON file that contains your key downloads to your computer. And finally export the environment variable:

   `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key/file`

After that, yo're ready to run `npm start` and go to the app's frontend and upload your file:

[image]